# Select2 doesnt show the AJAX results even though proper JSON format

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jquery-select2

This is my code:

```
$('.selecter_test').select2(
            {
                placeholder: 'Enter a username...',
                minimumInputLength: 0,
                allowClear: true,
                ajax: {
                    quietMillis: 200,
                    url: "/ajax/test",
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    data: function (term, page) {
                        return {
                            q: term
                        };
                    },
                    results: function (data, page) {

                        return { results: data.Results};
                    }

                }
            });
```

On the backend, I load an array with id and name and return it with `json_encode` function. My AJAX call response looks like this (viewed in Chrome under Network/Response tab):

```
[{"id":4017,"text":"10anabanana10"},{"id":4813,"text":"adria14na.bbb@gmail.com"}... ]
```

However, my Select2 just keeps showing the "Searching..." text and displays nothing. I've heard that I don't need to use the formatResult and formatSelectin functions since Im using the regular format.

Comment: `dataType: 'jsonp'`? What's up with that?

Comment: that's the format they suggest using on the docs page: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#ajax

Comment: "Remote" in that context means "on a domain other than your own". Which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: Anyway, it seems that you simply need to change the results callback to `return { results: data }`. I don't see any `Results` property here.

Comment: you're right about that, I just did but I still have the problem, it keeps showing "Search..." and nothing happens although I suppose the response is in the correct format...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the datatype parameter to json instead of jsonp. Found an answer somewhere else on Stackoverflow. Jon had a good point.